# html - how to open an image in the same web page, as layer on top of the original content

Tags: html

Sorry if my explanation is not clear, I am trying to open an image, on a web page.

I am not trying thou to have the image opened, replacing what is on the page; I am trying to open something like a pop up, so you can still see the original page below, and the full size image is on top; almost like if it is a modal view on iOS (sorry, no idea how to explain it). Something similar to what you see on many sites; when you click on an image, and the image just animate, getting bigger, while the webpage below gets "disabled" (the brightness decrease).

I know how to open the image in a popup, but I don't want to open a different window, I would like to just open the image when someone click on it; and then it close when they click either outside the image or on the image.

Saw few web sites that uses this technique, and was wondering if it require some sort of js to run, or if it is a new html extension. I will run these pages on our internal web server, using Safari as browser.

Can anyone give some info about this effect? My search on Google return mostly popup window, but not what I am looking for.

Comment: This effect is called lightbox, it is done with Javacript.

Comment: To add to that, the popup is called a modal window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Image inside div tag in the below code:

```
$(".link").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".popup").fadeIn(300,function(){$(this).focus();});
});

$('.close').click(function() {
   $(".popup").fadeOut(300);
});
$(".popup").on('blur',function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(300);
});
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LxauG/10/

Comment: Thanks! This works also via simple html? I see that on the link that you posted, there is also code for CSS and HTML; I could add the CSS code on my CSS file, and that will allow me to use the effect?